# What should I do if I want to click button on the new page while running snippet on chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I try to **run some JS snippet in chrome dev tools**, but not sure what I should do here. Can anyone help here? Thanks.

Take StackOverflow site for example. The script clicks the navigator tab "Jobs" to a new page then clicks the button "Create alert" on it.
[image]
see image for more information.

f1 works separately and also f2, but they do not work if I put them together.**what should I do if I hope them work together?**

```html
function f1(){
   //click the nav-jobs
   document.getElementById("nav-jobs").click();
}

function f2(){
   // create the button "Create alert" on the job page
   document.getElementById("reg-alert-model").click();
}

f1();
setTimeout(f2, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function call `f2()` will not occur because a page transition has already occurred after executing `f1()`.

JavaScript function calls do not persist in the call stack between page transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what should I do if I wang to do that.

Comment: Use a testing framework like Selenium (among others), or a user script runner, such as GreaseMonkey/Tampermonkey so that your functions aren't bound to the page context.

Answer (score 0):

When a page is reloaded or a new page is loaded, the entire context of the previous page is cleared/reset. So you can't keep a timer running over a document change. Naturally, when running them separately (no, not *seperately*), there are no context changes, so it works as you expect. But if you change the context in between, everything is lost, including the timer. Using the developer tools does not do any magic in keeping the context, it does not really matter whether you run it in the console or in the "page code".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what should I do if I wang to do that.